# Meteor http get call

Tags: javascript, meteor

Im trying to get a working http.get client function working in Meteor. 
However I keep getting my own page as result.

Here is my code:

```
Meteor.http.get("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk", function (error, result) {
if(error) {
    console.log('http get FAILED!');
} else {
    console.log('http get SUCCES');
    if (result.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log('Status code = 200!');
        console.log(result.content);
    }
}
});
```

I would expect that it returned a json object containing weather information.
Do I miss something here?

Thanks.

Comment: Found my solution! In the first place you need to add the http:// of https:// in front of the URL.

I used the Meteor Methods to do the stuff for me:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please update the url by adding `http://` at beginning.

Moreover make this call from your server, i.e. Make a method that contains the above code and call that method via `Meteor.call()`;

Please see [Meteor.methods()](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods) and [Meteor.call()](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_call)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I tried answering my own question just this moment, however i wasn't allowed.

The http:// did the trick and I used the Meteor methods function serverside

Comment: Hmmm.. thats because `Meteor.http.get()` needs absolute urls starting with `http://` or `https://`.

Comment: You will get incompatible protocol error if you use http:// and your website is using https, many services support the // notation to avoid this. So test to see if you can use your url like this: //api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk